# Converting a system of ODE to a single higher order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If we have the system of differential equations:

$$x^{(2)}(t)=\alpha\left(y(t)+\frac{x(t)-2x^3(t)}{7}\right)$$

$$y^{(2)}(t)=x(t)-y(t)+z(t)$$

$$z^{(2)}(t)=-\frac{-1}{100}y(t)$$

How do I convert it to a single ODE of higher order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{cases}x^{(2)}(t)=\alpha\biggl(y(t)+\dfrac{x(t)-2x^3(t)}{7}\biggr)~......(1)\\y^{(2)}(t)=x(t)-y(t)+z(t)~......(2)\\z^{(2)}(t)=-\dfrac{-1}{100}y(t)~......(3)\end{cases}$ , $\alpha\neq0$

From $(2)$ , $y^{(4)}(t)=x^{(2)}(t)-y^{(2)}(t)+z^{(2)}(t)=x^{(2)}(t)-y^{(2)}(t)+\dfrac{y(t)}{100}$

From $(1)$ , $y(t)=\dfrac{x^{(2)}(t)}{\alpha}+\dfrac{2x^3(t)-x(t)}{7}$

$y^{(1)}(t)=\dfrac{x^{(3)}(t)}{\alpha}+\dfrac{6x^2(t)x^{(1)}(t)}{7}-\dfrac{x^{(1)}(t)}{7}$

$y^{(2)}(t)=\dfrac{x^{(4)}(t)}{\alpha}+\dfrac{6x^2(t)x^{(2)}(t)}{7}+\dfrac{12x(t)(x^{(1)}(t))^2}{7}-\dfrac{x^{(2)}(t)}{7}$

$y^{(3)}(t)=\dfrac{x^{(5)}(t)}{\alpha}+\dfrac{6x^2(t)x^{(3)}(t)}{7}+\dfrac{36x(t)x^{(1)}(t)x^{(2)}(t)}{7}+\dfrac{12(x^{(1)}(t))^3}{7}-\dfrac{x^{(3)}(t)}{7}$

$y^{(4)}(t)=\dfrac{x^{(6)}(t)}{\alpha}+\dfrac{6x^2(t)x^{(4)}(t)}{7}+\dfrac{48x(t)x^{(1)}(t)x^{(3)}(t)}{7}+\dfrac{36x(t)(x^{(2)}(t))^2}{7}+\dfrac{72(x^{(1)}(t))^2x^{(2)}(t)}{7}-\dfrac{x^{(4)}(t)}{7}$

$\therefore\dfrac{x^{(6)}(t)}{\alpha}+\dfrac{6x^2(t)x^{(4)}(t)}{7}+\dfrac{48x(t)x^{(1)}(t)x^{(3)}(t)}{7}+\dfrac{36x(t)(x^{(2)}(t))^2}{7}+\dfrac{72(x^{(1)}(t))^2x^{(2)}(t)}{7}-\dfrac{x^{(4)}(t)}{7}=x^{(2)}(t)-\dfrac{x^{(4)}(t)}{\alpha}-\dfrac{6x^2(t)x^{(2)}(t)}{7}-\dfrac{12x(t)(x^{(1)}(t))^2}{7}+\dfrac{x^{(2)}(t)}{7}+\dfrac{x^{(2)}(t)}{100\alpha}+\dfrac{2x^3(t)-x(t)}{700}$

$\dfrac{x^{(6)}(t)}{\alpha}+\dfrac{6x^2(t)x^{(4)}(t)}{7}-\dfrac{(\alpha-7)x^{(4)}(t)}{7\alpha}+\dfrac{48x(t)x^{(1)}(t)x^{(3)}(t)}{7}+\dfrac{36x(t)(x^{(2)}(t))^2}{7}+\dfrac{72(x^{(1)}(t))^2x^{(2)}(t)}{7}+\dfrac{6x^2(t)x^{(2)}(t)}{7}-\dfrac{(800\alpha+7)x^{(2)}(t)}{700\alpha}+\dfrac{12x(t)(x^{(1)}(t))^2}{7}-\dfrac{2x^3(t)-x(t)}{700}=0$

$700x^{(6)}(t)+600\alpha x^2(t)x^{(4)}(t)-100(\alpha-7)x^{(4)}(t)+4800\alpha x(t)x^{(1)}(t)x^{(3)}(t)+3600\alpha x(t)(x^{(2)}(t))^2+7200\alpha(x^{(1)}(t))^2x^{(2)}(t)+600\alpha x^2(t)x^{(2)}(t)-(800\alpha+7)x^{(2)}(t)+1200\alpha x(t)(x^{(1)}(t))^2-2\alpha x^3(t)+\alpha x(t)=0$

Comment: Thank you! I thought there was an easier general method.